# BlueImp FileUpload not uploading files after certain size

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

I have implemented blueimps fileupload and it works great for any file up to about 30mb. I have set the maxRequestedLength to over 100mb plus IIS 7 is set to allow file uploads of larger than this.

When uploading a file that is larger than 30mb it just fires the fail option without ever having hit the code behind.

```js
$('#fu-my-simple-upload').fileupload({
            url: '/SubmissionPortal/UploadFile',
            dataType: 'json',
            maxFileSize: '@ViewBag.MaxFileSize' ,
            add: function (e, data) {
                jqXHRData = data
            },
            done: function (event, data) {
                alert("done");
                if (data.result.isUploaded) {
                    $("#tbx-file-path").val("No file chosen...");
                    $('input[type=submit]').click();
                }
                else {
                    alert(data.result.message);
                }                    
            },
            fail: function (event, data) {                
                if (data.files[0].error) {
                    alert(data.files[0].error);
                }
            },
            progress: function (e, data) {
                var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
                $('#progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
            }
        });
```

any ideas of what I am missing or doing wrong? I've searched for a few hours now and i can't find anything that explains why it stops working at such an arbitrary cut off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out i was missing a setting for IIS 7. i had the correct setting for IIS 6 so after adding the following it worked:

```
<security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="104857600" />
      </requestFiltering>
</security>
```

Answer (score 1):

Watch your Apache/PHP (or whatever web server you're using) upload limits. While this library has limits, the limits of the web server may be fooling you with a silent fail.

For instance, if using Apache & PHP, you need to edit the /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini file (how PHP layers itself inside of apache) and check the variables "memory_limit" and "post_max_size". Make sure "post_max_size" is set above what you have in this lib for a chunk limit and "memory_limit" even above that. If you don't, larger uploads will silently fail (see in apache logs to see it happening).

Answer (score 0):

After the url parameter try setting `maxFileSize: 52428800 (greater than 30 mb, say 50 mb)`...

Comment: this didn't work. I have tried various sizes in the maxFileSize parameter and it still fires the fail option after clicking on the button